# Zend FlashMessenger

Tags: php, zend-framework

Having an issue, don't know why this is happening:

In the first instance, everything works just fine, the message is set and it displays:

```
$this->_helper->FlashMessenger()
              ->setNamespace('success')
              ->addMessage('Success!')
              ->addMessage('User ' . $this->_request->getPost('user_name') . ' sucessfully added!');
$this->redirect('users/index');
```

However, in this instance, it fails with the message:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::direct()

```
$this->_helper->FlashMessenger()
              ->setNamespace('error')
              ->addMessage('Failure!')
              ->addMessage('User was not added, please see errors below.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
$this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')
              ->setNamespace('error')
              ->addMessage('Failure!')
              ->addMessage('User was not added, please see errors below.');
```

Comment: For some reason, your answer worked this time around even though the previous method was working on successes and not failures. Very odd. But thank you!